# FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory. This error occurs while giving a data path to upload datafile(present on desktop) in IBMQ

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

I am trying to implement [https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-machine-learning/machine-learning-qiskit-pytorch.html#3.-Let's-code!-](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-machine-learning/machine-learning-qiskit-pytorch.html#3.-Let%27s-code!-) in IBMQ using a dataset present on my desktop.

While uploading a dataset in IBM Q,

```
train = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/akanm/OneDrive/Desktop/Dataset/train.csv")
```

when I check the current working directory with the help of command os.cwd, it shows:

```
/home/jovyan.
```

How do I change the path to my desktop where the data file is present so that it does not give errors as:

No such file or directory
Tried the commands Change Directory but still, the same error occurs.

Comment: Did you try to upload your file directly on the quantum lab and then upload it on your notebook via `read_csv`?

Comment: I tried to upload the file directly but due to large size it doesn't upload. So, I tried with read_csv.

Comment: Then why not work locally? I mean directly work with notebooks on your computer and not via the lab, because as said in the answer I'm not sure it is possible to do what you want...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually, I have implemented the program with my dataset in Jupyter notebook. But the accuracy is coming out to be low. So, I wanted whether running the code in jupyter nodebook(with qiskit simulator in backend)  is similar to that in IBMQ. Or the quantum lab might increase the performance?

Comment: Kindly let me know if anyone has compared the two?

Comment: Did you get an answer? I am getting same error, while trying to import a file directory from my laptop via os.path.abs.path.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's a duplicate of a question by the same person that was closed and then deleted (https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/18208/55)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can easily change the path to your desktop since IBMQ's jupyter notebook is running on IBM's server, not your computer.

Maybe you could consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748355/change-working-directory-on-remote-location) but I haven't tried it myself so I'm not sure if it works.